# How to install TeXLive on Alpine Linux?

Tags: latex, alpine-linux

Is it possible to install texlive with tlmgr utility (from tug.org)? same question for installing  texmaker (or texstudio) latex editors from sources (rather than AppImage, flatpack or snap packages). Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your first question: Alpine has latex in community repository.
First, check if your community repository is enabled in `/etc/apk/repositories` (this is the example for latest stable alpine version):

```
# cat /etc/apk/repositories
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community
```

Then, you can add latex with:

`apk update && apk add texmf-dist texlive`

In regards of texmaker or texstudio, the latter is not available, while texmaker is available on `testing`.
In order to enable this repository, add to `/etc/apk/repositories` the following line:

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

Then, proceed as usual:

```
apk update && apk add texmaker
```

Since I've just ported texmaker, please wait from now few hours, so that the various mirror will synchronize, making texmaker package available.

Hope this helps!

.: Francesco

Comment: Thank you Francesco, it's solved now!